# How to delete the required string from vector<string>?

Tags: c++

I need to delete the required strings from `map<***,vector<string>> Events` by function `bool predicate(***,const string& event)`?

I'm tried to do this with algorithm:

```
for(auto& item : Events){
remove(item.second.begin(), item.second.end(), [predicate, item](string event){
return predicate(item.first, event);
}
}
```

But it not worked

Comment: Describe 'it not worked' in more detail. Did it remove something else? Did it not remove anything? Did it compile in the first palce? Also, create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a fair bit of confusion in your code. The following should do it

```
std::map<***, std::vector<std::string>> Events;

bool predicate(***, const std::string& event) {
    ...
}

for (auto& item : Events) {
    item.second.erase(std::remove_if(item.second.begin(), item.second.end(), 
        [item](const std::string& event) {
            return predicate(item.first, event);
    }), item.second.end());
}
```

The main issues with your code are

1. You should use `remove_if`, not `remove`.
2. You aren't calling `erase` on your vector. `remove_if` (and `remove`) do not by themselves remove anything. All they do is put the strings to be removed at the end of your vector and return an iterator to the first string to be removed. You have to call `vector::erase` to do the actual removal.